# How could I insert The row with multiple column in Qml

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

I am trying to prepare a tree Model and I have done this:

> treemodel.h

```
#include <QStandardItemModel>

class TreeModel : public QStandardItemModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    TreeModel( QObject *parent = nullptr );
private:
    QVector<TreeModel *> child_items;
    TreeModel* parent_item;
    static const int DisplayName;
    static const int DisplayInfo;
    static const int DisplayId;
};
```

> treemodel.cpp

```
#include "treemodel.h"
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include <QStandardItem>
#include <QAbstractItemModel>
#include <QString>
#include <QTreeView>
#include <iostream>
#include <QList>
#include <QModelIndex>


const int TreeModel::DisplayName = Qt::UserRole+1;
const int TreeModel::DisplayInfo = Qt::UserRole+2;
const int TreeModel::DisplayId = Qt::UserRole+3;

TreeModel::TreeModel( QObject *parent ) : QStandardItemModel(parent)
{
    QStandardItem *parentItem = this->invisibleRootItem();

    QHash<int, QByteArray> roles = roleNames();
    roles.insert(DisplayName, "A");
    roles.insert(DisplayInfo, "B");
    roles.insert(DisplayId, "C");
    setItemRoleNames(roles);

    QStandardItem *c1 = new QStandardItem;
    c1->setData("Sudip", DisplayName);
    QStandardItem *c2 = new QStandardItem;
    c2->setData("Ghimire", DisplayInfo);
    QStandardItem *c3 = new QStandardItem;
    c3->setData("Bahadur", DisplayId);
    QList<QStandardItem *> r1 { c1, c2, c3};
    parentItem->insertRow(0, r1);
}
```

> main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick 2.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Tree View Example")
    id: root
    TreeView{
        id: tree_view
        model: TreeModel
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        width: root.width
        height: root.height
        sortIndicatorVisible: true
        alternatingRowColors: false
        backgroundVisible: false
        TableViewColumn{
            role: "A"
            title: "Elements"
            width: 300
        }
        TableViewColumn{
            role: "B"
            title: "more"
            width: 300
        }
        TableViewColumn{
            role: "C"
            title: "I am some title"
            width: 300
        }
       /*
        MouseArea{
            anchors.fill: tree_view
            hoverEnabled: true
            onHoveredChanged: function(){
            }
        }
        */

    }
}
```

> main.cpp

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
TreeModel t_model;
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("TreeModel", &t_model);
```

But the reasult is

[image: this]

But I want to fill all column by a row. I think appendRow in treemodel.cpp should have done the wok. But its wired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because ur model doesn't know how to deal with your custom user role when QStandardItemModel::data() called to bind value in QML. So what you have to do is, override the data() function your TreeModel class and return the data for ur custom roles. You should add below code to ur TreeModel class.

```
QVariant TreeModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    QVariant value;

    if (index.isValid()) {
        if (role <= Qt::UserRole) {
            value = QStandardItemModel::data(index, role);
        }
        else if(role == DisplayName)
        {
            value = QStandardItemModel::data(index, DisplayName);
        }
        else if(role == DisplayInfo)
        {
            int columnIdx = role - Qt::UserRole - 1;
            QModelIndex modelIndex = this->index(index.row(), columnIdx);
            value = QStandardItemModel::data(modelIndex, DisplayInfo);
        }
        else if(role == DisplayId)
        {
            int columnIdx = role - Qt::UserRole - 1;
            QModelIndex modelIndex = this->index(index.row(), columnIdx);
            value = QStandardItemModel::data(modelIndex, DisplayId);
        }
        else
        {
            // undefined role.
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: It works Like a charm. Now I have another question. But please don't assume that I am asking for help without doing much from myself.I had tried several toturial and documentation just crashes me. 
How could I create DOM structure from the html loaded in qml webvie. Okey I will do the prasing and everything else by myself, I just want to get the idea to insert The DOM name whenever I needed and also I want to get the data later. Could You please  help me?